# MySQL get the last record if TRUE then get the next record on increment

Tags: php, mysql

I have this database of events and a function in PHP that logs/insert data into it every 1 hour which is either HOT or COLD and another function that inserts a record every minute just need to insert a couple of different data but when it comes to displaying it, it should just get the last status of the record if it's HOT or COLD.

so basically the behavior is like below, the every-minute frequency has no status data so I need to get the status from the last record that has a status or is not empty.

| ID | Status | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COLD | every minute |
| 2 | COLD | every minute |
| 3 | COLD | every minute |
| 4 | COLD | every minute |
| 5 | COLD | hourly |
| 6 | HOT | every minute |
| 7 | HOT | every minute |
| 8 | HOT | every minute |
| 9 | HOT | every minute |
| 10 | HOT | hourly |

I tried the below query to get the last record that is either HOT or COLD but it was applied on every record inside the loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   if($row['status'] == "HOT"){
     echo "HOT";
   }else if($row['status'] == "COLD"){
      echo "COLD";
   }else{
     //if the record status is not equal to HOT or COLD
     $hourly_record = get_last_record();
     echo $hourly_record['status'];
   }

 }
```

the get_last_record() function

```
  function get_last_record() {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status = 'HOT' OR status = 'COLD' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
        //some execution
       return $rows;
    }
```

But the output is once it gets a status of either HOT or COLD all of the records will share the same status, is there a way on MySQL or PHP to get the next record with a different status?

Comment: so the function `get_last_record()` gives you data properly, then why loop? As well as it's unclear what you actually trying to achieve here. Please elaborate a bit more in terms of what's your expected outcome and what currently you are getting.

Comment: In the SQL this must be a typo `OR status = 'GOLD'` ~ surely that ought to be `OR status = 'COLD'`

Answer (score 1):

Change your select query with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATALENGTH(status) > 0 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```